# Refresh Boostrap-Vue table after deleting a row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Bootstrap-Vue for my datatables and got the following table within my dashboard:

[image]

I can succesfully delete items by clicking on the trash icon. It sends an AJAX request using Axios. However, after deletion it still displays the item until I manually refresh the web page. How do I solve this? I don't want to make another AJAX request to load in the updated version, I think the best way to solve it is just remove the deleted item row from the datatable.

I tried giving my table a ref tag and call a refresh function using `this.$refs.table.refresh();` but with no success.

My code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <b-modal ref="myModalRef" hide-footer title="Delete product">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p>
                <div class="col-md-6 pl-0">
                    <a href="#" v-on:click="deleteItem(selectedID)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-block">Confirm</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
                    <a href="#" v-on:click="$refs.myModalRef.hide()" class="btn btn-tertiary btn-sm btn-block">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </b-modal>
    <div id="main-wrapper" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>Mijn producten</h4>
                <p>Hier vind zich een overzicht van uw producten plaats.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 mt-3 text-left">
                <router-link class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" :to="{ name: 'create-product'}">Create new product</router-link>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 mt-3 text-right">
                <b-form-input v-model="filter" class="table-search" placeholder="Type to Search" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr>
                <b-table ref="table" show-empty striped hover responsive :items="posts" :fields="fields" :filter="filter" :current-page="currentPage" :per-page="perPage">
                    <template slot="title" slot-scope="data">
                        {{ data.item.title|truncate(30) }}
                    </template>
                    <template slot="description" slot-scope="data">
                        {{ data.item.description|truncate(50) }}
                    </template>
                    <template slot="public" slot-scope="data">
                        <i v-if="data.item.public === 0" title="Unpublished" class="fa fa-circle false" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i v-else title="Published" class="fa fa-circle true" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </template>
                    <template slot="date" slot-scope="data">
                        {{ data.item.updated_at }}
                    </template>
                    <template slot="actions" slot-scope="data">
                        <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
                        <a v-on:click="editItem(data.item.id)" class="icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" v-on:click="getID(data.item.id)" class="icon"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                    </template>
                </b-table>
                <b-pagination :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage" class="my-0 pagination-sm" />
            </div>

        </div><!-- Row -->

    </div><!-- Main Wrapper -->
</div>
```

```
<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                posts: [],
                filter: null,
                currentPage: 1,
                perPage: 10,
                totalRows: null,
                selectedID: null,
                fields: [
                    {
                        key: 'title',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'description',
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'public',
                        sortable: true,

                    },
                    {
                        key: 'date',
                        label: 'Last updated',
                        sortable: true,
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'actions',
                    }

                ],
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getResults();
        },
        methods: {
            // Our method to GET results from a Laravel endpoint
            getResults() {
                axios.get('/api/products')

                    .then(response => {
                        this.posts = response.data;
                        this.totalRows = response.data.length;
                    });
            },
            getID: function(id){
                this.selectedID = id;
                this.$refs.myModalRef.show();
            },
            deleteItem: function (id) {
                axios.delete('/api/products/' + id)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.$refs.myModalRef.hide();
                        this.$refs.table.refresh();

                    });

            },
            editItem: function (id){
                this.$router.push({ path: 'products/' + id });
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The deleteItem method should be like this:

```
        deleteItem(id) {
            axios.delete('/api/products/' + id)
                .then(response => {
                   const index = this.posts.findIndex(post => post.id === id) // find the post index 
                   if (~index) // if the post exists in array
                     this.posts.splice(index, 1) //delete the post
                });

        },
```

So basically you don't need any refresh. If you remove the item for `posts` array Vue will automatically handle this for you and your table will be "refreshed"

Comment: sorry, it was me, i hit downvote accidentally i want to hit +1 because you're giving a good alternative solution

Comment: Ah ok no worries. Did my answer helped you?

Comment: i'm not the asker, i already gave a solution using `this.posts= this.posts.filter(post=>post.id!=id)`

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad. You solution is great but splice is faster. `filter` will loop through all items of array. However your answer needs up vote since it is correct. I am going to do it now.

Comment: thanks, this worked! May I ask why you're using const?

Comment: Glad to read that I helped you. I am using const because the variable index is not going to change. In such cases it is recommended to use const.

Answer (score 5):

try to remove that post with the given *id* after the successful delete  :

```
     axios.delete('/api/products/' + id)
                .then(response => {
                 this.posts= this.posts.filter(post=>post.id!=id)

                });
```

Comment: thanks this was helpful. I had a similar use case that after delete a record, i wasn't sure if i should call the method to fetch the records again and rebuild the array for the table OR to delete the records and using your approach filter out those records, instead of calling backend resources

Comment: No need to call backend resource because the delete operation is successfully done

Answer (score 0):

```
 axios.delete('/api/products/' + id)
                .then(response => {
                this.getResults();

                });
```